# What is the equivalent of Oracle’s REF CURSOR in MySQL when using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc, ref-cursor

**In Oracle I can declare a reference cursor...**

```
TYPE t_spool IS REF CURSOR RETURN spool%ROWTYPE;
```

**...and use it to pass a cursor as the return value...**

```
FUNCTION end_spool
    RETURN t_spool
    AS
    v_spool t_spool;
    BEGIN
        COMMIT;
        OPEN v_spool FOR
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                spool
            WHERE
                key = g_spool_key
            ORDER BY
                seq;
        RETURN v_spool;
    END end_spool;
```

**...and then capture it as a result set using JDBC...**

```
private Connection conn;
private CallableStatement stmt;
private OracleResultSet rset;
[...clip...]
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call " + call + "}");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.execute();
rset = (OracleResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
```

**What is the equivalent in MySQL?**

Answer (score 7):

Mysql has an implicit cursor that you can magically return from a stored procedure if you issue a select.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM test_table;
END;
```

and in your java code:

```
String query = "{CALL TEST()}";
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query,
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: That's incredible! Is this a documented feature of both the MySQL database **AND** JDBC driver?

Comment: Well, the docs of jdbc show a difference between the execute method, which you used in your question, and the executeQuery, which I used. executeQuery is designed to return a result set, without resorting to out parameters. Although, I don't know if that is the official way to do it, I haven't used mysql for quite some time now

Comment: I don't think anyone refers to this as an implicit cursor (though technically correct, as when talking about SQL Server and Sybase, it's said that cursors are used internally and not able to be returned). If you're returning the results of a multi-column select, the JDBC spec just retrieves a ResultSet. If you have one row and one column, you can just retreive the value. I still don't see the use of returning a Cursor, as in Oracle, over returning the ResultSet.

Answer (score 3):

Googling on cursors in MySQL, it doesn't seem like you can actually return a Cursor from a Proc or Function.  Additionally, I found the following in the [MySQL JDBC manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

"MySQL does not support SQL cursors, and the JDBC driver doesn't emulate them, so "setCursorName()" has no effect."

In general, I believe Oracle's implementation here breaks JDBC, and is not used elsewhere (MySQL, MSSQL, etc).  You should be returning your results as a select statement and iterating over the JDBC ResultSet, as is standard (and intended) practice when using JDBC.

Comment: It is definitely outside of the JDBC spec.  Oracle and to some degree PostgreSQL have implemented the extension.  It is very useful and I had hoped for the same from MySQL.

Comment: How much more useful is it than just iterating over a ResultSet?

Comment: The H2 database also supports functions (or aliases) returning ResultSets: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

Answer (score -1):

fill a temporary table in a procedure and just read the temporary table... :)