# What is the equivalent of Oracle’s REF CURSOR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select, cursor

I am trying to make a procdure in mysql that returns me an array with the result, I used to do with the oracle ref cursor, but in mysql do not know how to proceed, 
I have to pass parameters too...

Anyone know how I can do, or have an example to show me? Thank you very much...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Oracle’s REF CURSOR in MySQL when using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273929/what-is-the-equivalent-of-oracle-s-ref-cursor-in-mysql-when-using-jdbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no analog of REF CURSOR in MySQL. Stored procedures and functions allow to pass and return only scalar datata types, see the reference here - [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

MySQL cannot operate with arrays. A workaround is to use a [table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) (or TEMPORARY TABLE).

Also - take advantage of visual object editors and [stored procedure debugger](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Answer (score 6):

MySQL doesn't have a refcursor like Oracle. If you are planning to write a stored procedure that returns multiple rows/result set in MySQL just do

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sample`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `sample`(p_rank IN INT)
BEGIN
select * from MyTable where id=p_rank;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call `sample();`. It will return a result set which you can use.