# Mysql Ref Cursor with Mysql ADO.NET provider

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273929/what-is-the-equivalent-of-oracles-ref-cursor-in-mysql-when-using-jdbc) that you can implicitly return a refcursor from a stored procedure with MySql's JDBC driver. I am working with a MVC 4 project and I'm using a MySql database for customer data.

How do I reference or access the implicit ref cursor from the MySqlCommand after I have executed the stored procedure.

Comment: I figured it out, you just run the command as if you are doing any query. The ref cursor will be accessible via the MySqlDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ExecuteReader` on your stored procedure database command, and you will get back a data reader which traverses the 'implicit cursor' just like reading the results of a normal `SELECT` not inside a procedure.